# discord.py, on_member_update() not detecting status updates, but detects other events

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, status

I'm still learning python/discord.py and am attempting to build a simple bot to detect changes in a users status (online/offline); shown below is an implementation which should detect all member updates.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)

target_channel_id = <id here>

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot ready")

@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    channel = bot.get_channel(target_channel_id)
    await channel.send("Member updated!")
    print("member updated!")

bot.run("<token here>")
```

I have my intents enabled properly as evidenced by the bot responding to name/role changes, but nothing appears to happen with status changes. Like I said I'm still new to both python and discord.py so I'm not sure if I just don't know something, but in the documentation it says that on_member_update() should be called with status changes, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Thank you for reading!

Comment: try printing `before.status` and `after.status` and reply to me

Comment: When changing roles/names, it prints out the status as expected, but when changing status nothing prints out leading me to believe that the function is not even being called on status changes.

Comment: did u print what i said and just tell me observation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the below three intents in your code and your code will start working if status update occurs

```py
intents = discord.Intents( guilds=True,members=True,presences=True)
```